# LINQ get the best match from the list comparing strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have code where I try to find `QProduct` by `productName` in a `List<QProduct>` (lqp) usinq LINQ. The variable `productNameInaccurate` I get from file name and often contains some other text usually at the end of the string. So for example the `productName = '0/2'` and the `productNameInaccurate` that I get from fileName is `'0/2 new'` etc.

I have this code:

```
 //Get inaccurate product name from filename     
 productNameInaccurate = fileName.Substring(ind + 1, ind2 - ind - 1).Replace("-", "/");

 //Get filtered list of products
 List<QProduct> filtered = lqp.Where(x=>productNameInaccurate.StartsWith(x.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

  //Some more filtering - here I need to get best match by productName
  if (isDop)
         qProduct = filtered.Where(x => x.normy.StartsWith("ČSN EN")).FirstOrDefault();
  else
         qProduct = filtered.Where(x => !x.normy.StartsWith("ČSN EN")).FirstOrDefault();
```

It works ok, but I have also `productName = '32/63'` and `productName = '32/63 B I'`. This code finds `QProduct` that has `productName == '32/63'` even if `productNameInaccurate == '32/63 BI'`.

What I need is to find best match from the list of `QProduct`, so that for `productNameInaccurate='0/2 new'` I get  `QProduct.Name = '0/2'` and for `productNameInaccurate='32/63 Bi'` I get  `QProduct.Name = '32/63 B II'` instead of `QProduct.Name = '32/63'`. Ideally get the `filtered` list sorted by count of matching characters.

Comment: I think its not possible. Simple loop will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ideally get the filtered list sorted by count of matching characters."

```
// Get the filtered list and sort by count of matching characters
IEnumerable<QProduct> filtered = lqp
    .Where(x=>productNameInaccurate.StartsWith(x.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .OrderByDesc(x => Fitness(x.ProductName, productNameInaccurate));

static int Fitness(string individual, string target) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(individual.Length, target.Length))
                     .Count(i => individual[i] == target[i]);
}
```